# Do I need to create multiple reverse zones for a single IP address with Bind?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind

I've followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093) tutorial in setting up Bind on my VPS. I created a dummy domain (test.com) and pointed it to `192.168.0.3` - Same IP as used in the tutorial.

It's all working nicely.

What I'm curious about is: Lets say I have 10 domains on the one IP. Obviously, I would need to create a new zone for each of these domains... But, do I need to create multiple reverse zones? Given that each domain will point to the same IP, can I just use the one reverse zone?

Answer (score 1):

As reverse zones are matched against ip ranges, an ip address can only exist in one reverse zone. Hence a ip address can only have one PTR record. Just because multiple domain names can point to the same ip address doesn't mean that that ip address can/must reverse to all of them.